# What is the best way to handle overlapping lexer patterns that are sensitive to context?

Tags: parsing, antlr, lexer, structurizr

I'm attempting to write an Antlr grammar for parsing the [C4 DSL](https://github.com/structurizr/dsl/blob/master/docs/language-reference.md).  However, the DSL has a number of places where the grammar is very open ended, resulting in overlapping lexer rules (in the sense that multiple token rules match).

For example, the [workspace rule](https://github.com/structurizr/dsl/blob/master/docs/language-reference.md#workspace) can have a child [properties](https://github.com/structurizr/dsl/blob/master/docs/language-reference.md#properties) element defining `<name> <value>` pairs.  This is a valid file:

```
workspace "Name" "Description" {
    properties {
        xyz "a string property"
        nonstring nodoublequotes
    }
}
```

The issue I'm running into is that the rules for the `<name>` and `<value>` have to be very broad, basically anything except whitespace.  Also, properties with spaces with double quotes will match my `STRING` token.

My current solution is the grammar below, using `property_element: BLOB | STRING;` to match values and `BLOB` to match names.  Is there a better way here?  If I could make context sensitive lexer tokens I would make `NAME` and `VALUE` tokens instead. In the actual grammar I define case insensitive name tokens for thinks like `workspace` and `properties`.  This allows me to easily match the existing DSL semantics, but raises the wrinkle that a property name or value of `workspace` will tokenize to `K_WORKSPACE`.

```
grammar c4mce;

workspace : 'workspace' (STRING (STRING)?)?  '{' NL workspace_body '}';

workspace_body : (workspace_element NL)* ;
workspace_element: 'properties' '{' NL (property_element NL)* '}';

property_element: BLOB property_value;
property_value : BLOB | STRING;

BLOB: [\p{Alpha}]+;
STRING: '"' (~('\n' | '\r' | '"' | '\\') | '\\\\' | '\\"')* '"';
NL: '\r'? '\n';
WS: [ \t]+ -> skip;
```

This tokenizes to

```
[@0,0:8='workspace',<'workspace'>,1:0]
[@1,10:15='"Name"',<STRING>,1:10]
[@2,17:29='"Description"',<STRING>,1:17]
[@3,31:31='{',<'{'>,1:31]
[@4,32:32='\n',<NL>,1:32]
[@5,37:46='properties',<'properties'>,2:4]
[@6,48:48='{',<'{'>,2:15]
[@7,49:49='\n',<NL>,2:16]
[@8,58:60='xyz',<BLOB>,3:8]
[@9,62:80='"a string property"',<STRING>,3:12]
[@10,81:81='\n',<NL>,3:31]
[@11,90:98='nonstring',<BLOB>,4:8]
[@12,100:113='nodoublequotes',<BLOB>,4:18]
[@13,114:114='\n',<NL>,4:32]
[@14,119:119='}',<'}'>,5:4]
[@15,120:120='\n',<NL>,5:5]
[@16,121:121='}',<'}'>,6:0]
[@17,122:122='\n',<NL>,6:1]
[@18,123:122='<EOF>',<EOF>,7:0]
```

This is all fine, and I suppose it's as much as the DSL grammar gives me.  Is there a better way to handle situations like this?
As I expand the grammar I expect to have a lot of `BLOB` tokens simply because creating a narrower token in the lexer would be pointless because `BLOB` would match instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the classic *keywords-as-identifier* problem. If you want that a specific char combination, which is lexed as keyword, can also be used as a normal identifier in certain places, then you have to list this keyword as possible alternative. For example:

```
property_element: (BLOB | K_WORKSPACE) property_value;
property_value : BLOB | STRING | K_WORKSPACE;
```